# In excel, is there a way to pull specific data for a report besides a VLOOKUP?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I want to pull a variety of different data from several reports into a Master File of sorts based on the unique identifier present within each report. I wanted to use a VLOOKUP for this feature, but I wanted to know if there's another way to gather the specific reports and have a easier way to update the data accordingly if new data exists in the reports in the future, as well as a way to pull the file number in an adjacent column. Thank you for understanding and for any advice/ help.

Comment: Check out index() with match() - much more flexible : can move left of the indexed column (vlookup can’t) or can have the index column on one sheet and the result in a different place or even on another sheet.

Comment: See an exmple here ,give it a vote if it helps you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/55785168/4961700

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here is an example of `INDEX` & `MATCH`

`VLOOKUP` only works when the common column in both the table is on the left side of the desired values column.

Now for more powerful lookup function you can use `INDEX` & `MATCH` functions.

[image]

To get the desired result you have to input these values in `INDEX` - `INDEX(Table, Row, Column)`

`MATCH` takes 3 values - `MATCH(Cell, Column, [-1, 0, 1])` ---- Here `0` is used to find the exact match

Now if you combine the both functions you can replace the `Row` of `INDEX` with the `MATCH` function.

It will be like this - `INDEX(Table, MATCH(Cell, Column, 0), Column)`

My formula in the sheet is `INDEX(I:J, MATCH(D2, J:J, 0), 1)`

Here I have used 1 as the `Column` of `INDEX` because I wanted the values of `GTIN-13`.

Comment: Thanks @SolarMike I just edited my answer to make it more intuitive.

Comment: Neat, deleting my comments.

Comment: You should't have deleted those as they were informative & educational.